# momentjs add moment object into array

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

***js:***

```
service.search = function (goDate, returnDate) {

  var outwardInterval = {};
  outwardInterval.start = moment(goDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(3, 'day');
  outwardInterval.end = moment(goDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').add(3, 'day');

  matrice.outwardDates = buildDateArray(outwardInterval);

}
var buildDateArray = function (interval) {
    var array = [];
    var currentDate = interval.start;
    do {
        array.push(currentDate);
        currentDate.add(1, 'day');
    } while (!currentDate.isAfter(interval.end));

    return array;
};
```

My output:

[image]

Why in my array i have the same value ..?

***Update***:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u93g87qc/1/)

Comment: I tried to fix it.. But can't. But if you wish to do this using plain javascript, I may help you there.

Comment: @Ved how can i using it ?

Comment: can you explain what is the requirement. ?

Comment: What i Guessed, on that basis, I am posting an sample answer. Check it

Comment: @Ved I do not see your answer

Comment: Check it.. I have posted just now. I don't think it is your answer. But It may help you some what..

Comment: @Ved it's working but not exactly what i want, in my array i want moment object

Comment: Ok.. I ma looking to your code..

Comment: You are making mistake in printing the array..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67851/discussion-between-mercer-and-ved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending My comment:

```
function GetDates(startDate, daysToAdd) {
  var aryDates = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <= daysToAdd; i++) {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
   aryDates.push(DayAsString(currentDate.getDay()) + ", " + currentDate.getDate() + " " + MonthAsString(currentDate.getMonth()) + " " + currentDate.getFullYear());
  }

  return aryDates;
 }

 function MonthAsString(monthIndex) {
  var d=new Date();
  var month=new Array();
  month[0]="Jan";
  month[1]="Feb";
  month[2]="March";
  month[3]="April";
  month[4]="May";
  month[5]="June";
  month[6]="July";
  month[7]="Aug";
  month[8]="Sep";
  month[9]="Oct";
  month[10]="Nov";
  month[11]="Dec";

  return month[monthIndex];
 }

 function DayAsString(dayIndex) {
  var weekdays = new Array(7);
  weekdays[0] = "Sun";
  weekdays[1] = "Mon";
  weekdays[2] = "Tue";
  weekdays[3] = "Wed";
  weekdays[4] = "Thu";
  weekdays[5] = "Fri";
  weekdays[6] = "Sat";

  return weekdays[dayIndex];
 }

 var startDate = new Date();
 var aryDates = GetDates(startDate, 7);
 console.log(aryDates);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u93g87qc/2/

Answer (score -1):

Actually you're not getting the same date for every value in the array. You're fighting `moment.js` here. If you slightly modify your code to execute the `toDate` method of the `moment` you'll see that it's working just fine:

```
var matrice = { };
var service = { };

service.search = function (goDate, returnDate) {

  var outwardInterval = {};
  outwardInterval.start = moment(goDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(3, 'day');
  outwardInterval.end = moment(goDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').add(3, 'day');

  matrice.outwardDates = buildDateArray(outwardInterval);

}

var buildDateArray = function (interval) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('Start: ', interval.start.toDate());
    console.log('End: ', interval.end.toDate());

    var array = [];
    var currentDate = interval.start;

    console.log('Initial date: ', currentDate.toDate());

    do {
        array.push(currentDate.toDate());
        currentDate.add(1, 'days');

        console.log('Current date: ', currentDate.toDate());
    } while (!currentDate.isAfter(interval.end));

    return array;
};

service.search('2014-12-25');
```

Output:

```
Start:  Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
End:  Sun Dec 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Initial date:  Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Tue Dec 23 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Wed Dec 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Thu Dec 25 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Fri Dec 26 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Sat Dec 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Sun Dec 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Current date:  Mon Dec 29 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```